# Gmail API can't publish any message to Pub/Sub platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I have set everything up in the GCP. And my server can receive the message, after I manually published a message.
[image]
But the question is: **when I send an e-mail to the e-mail account,  there is no any notification in Pub-Sub system and my webhook sever !**

**Below graph is the proof that my server can receive the message, after I manually published a message.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And as the graph above, when I call the list history API, I can check there is the test mail information I just sent.**

Besides, I have successfully called the `watch` API, and it returned:

```
{'historyId': '7688', 'expiration': '1574928158379'}
```

Here is my watch call:

```
In [9]:     def set_watch(self, topicName):
   ...:         request = {
   ...:             'labelIds': ['INBOX', 'UNREAD', 'STARRED'],
   ...:             'labelFilterAction': 'include',
   ...:             #'labelIds': ['UNREAD'],
   ...:             'topicName': topicName
   ...:         }
   ...:         res = self.service.users().watch(
   ...:             userId=self.userId, body=request).execute()
   ...:         print(res)
```

Comment: it seemed the `watch` api didn't work, but it returned normally.

Comment: Did you grant `publish` permissions to [`gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)?

Comment: How to check that. And I think it is not like the permission issue.

Comment: I haven't tested it but I ask because it is one of the required steps in the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#grant_publish_rights_on_your_topic), which also shows how to add them. If so you should see unauthorized Pub/Sub API calls in the GCP Console

Comment: you're right, after reading the doc and thinking again, I figure out where I missed. I missed the step adding the `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com` Thanks alot !

Comment: can you leave an answer, I give you the reputation. thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for confirming, adding answer now

Comment: I'm facing the same problem where should I add the watch call code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the `set_watch` call returns a `200` and a `HistoryId` with a valid `expiration` makes me think that the watch is correctly set up and the issue might be on the Pub/Sub side.

The difference with the tests, where you are able to publish to the topic and trigger a server response, is that you are using one of your accounts. According to the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#grant_publish_rights_on_your_topic), the watch message is published with a Google-managed service account:

> Cloud Pub/Sub requires that you grant Gmail privileges to publish
>   notifications to your topic.
>
> To do this, you need to grant publish privileges to
>   gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com. You can do this using the
>   Cloud Pub/Sub Developer Console permissions interface following the
>   resource-level access control instructions.

where the links point [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/cloudpubsub/topicList) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#set_topic_level_access). Following least privileges principles, I would recommend to grant permissions on a resource (topic) level.

**Note:**

the settings in the panel will look like this:
[image]